# Magento shows different prices on category page and PDP

Tags: magento

On my shop the category page use:

```
echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)
```

On Product detail page is uses:

```
echo strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()));
```

The category page shows price incl tax
PDP shows price excl tax

I need it to show incl tax in both places.

How do I achieve that

Comment: `echo strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()));` does not seems like Magento way of doing things to me, is this from a custom module ?

Answer (score 2):

In your product view page replace:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice())); ?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
```